# d3 tree with aligned leaves

Tags: tree, d3.js

I am interested in visualising phylogenetic trees using d3.

I had a look at many tree examples (well, there are plenty of them, thanks!)
but none of them seem to have the leaf nodes (usually extant species)
all aligned to the right like [here](http://fb2008_07.flybase.org/blast/species_tree.png).

What is the starting point if I want to convert this collapse tree [here](http://bl.ocks.org/4339083)?

Would be great to know more about it.

Cheers,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

If you are interested, have a look at this [cluster dendogram](http://bl.ocks.org/4063570)!